# why the cost of a query reduces using parallel hint?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-execution-plan, explain

in Oracle 12C, I have this query

```
select 
* from my_table t;
```

and if I run explain plain, the cost I get is **235597**

if I add the parallel hint like this

```
select /*+ parallel(16) */
* from my_table t;
```

explain plan gives a cost **16349**

about ***14 times less***

although I understand that the query is going to use 16 threads to solve the query,
I do not understand why the cost is reduced , and I even would expect a little more cost in order to manage the threads.
if you have $100 and divide the $100 among 16 people, you still have $100 less.

Comment: Hi Leo, please provide us with the execution plans you"ve got with and without hint. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cost is a magic number created by the optimizer to choose the *fastest* execution plan, not necessarily the most *efficient* plan. To compare serial and parallel plans, Oracle divides the cost of parallel plans based on the degree of parallelism.

For serial plans, cost and resource consumption are positively correlated so there's no conflict between speed and efficiency. But parallelism always requires more overhead than the equivalent serial operations - asking for parallelism is implicitly asking the optimizer to ignore efficiency and only optimize for speed.

But when we ask for parallelism, Oracle must still consider non-parallel execution plans. Even if we ask for `/*+ parallel(256) */`, and our system has an embarrassment of cores and IO, the fastest execution plan may be a serial plan with a unique index.

To compare the execution times between serial and parallel, Oracle calculates the cost of degree N as `ceil(serial cost / (0.9 * N))`. The 0.9 is useful because parallel improvement is never strictly a multiple of the number of threads. That equation is from Jonathan Lewis's book "Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals". For the costs in your question, `ceil(235597 / (0.9 * 16)) = 16361`, which is very close to your final cost of `16349`.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into the same book as Jon :-). To show you an example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id NUMBER, c VARCHAR2(4000));
INSERT /*+ APPEND*/ INTO my_table(id, c)
  SELECT object_id, LPAD(object_name, 3800, 'x') 
    FROM all_objects WHERE rownum <= 50000;
EXEC DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS(USER, 'my_table');
```

If you run the query with different degrees of parallelism, you arrive exactly at the cost estimates Jon mentions. Besides the estimated cost from explain plan I noted the measured runtime in seconds:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(t, 1) */ count(*) FROM my_table t;
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(t, 2) */ count(*) FROM my_table t;
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(t, 3) */ count(*) FROM my_table t;
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(t, 4) */ count(*) FROM my_table t;


Parallel   cost  seconds
       1  13635     1.27
       2   7570     1.29
       3   5046     1.32
       4   3785     1.35
```

So, the optimizers **estimates** that the costs are reduced when run in parallel. However, if they do in reality is a differnt matter.